# Cannot convert string to date in R

Tags: string, r, date, csv

I need your help to figure out the following problem-

I am trying to convert a date column from string to actual date format. I have tried using as.Date

However, it is showing an error message: 
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

the date column I have in csv file is like this:

Date

03/17/2003

05/31/2003

09/06/2003

10/18/2003

07/15/2003

09/19/2003

The problem is some of the dates are in string and some are in actual date format. I have tried to format it from excel - didn't work
Tried to copy and paste it to notepad and then import it again - didn't work either.

Answer (score 4):

You need to learn about the help system in R. One brief look at `help(as.Date)` may have told you about the *format* argument:

```
R> dt <- c("03/17/2003", "05/31/2003", "09/06/2003")
R> as.Date(dt, "%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "2003-03-17" "2003-05-31" "2003-09-06"
R>
```

*Edit:* These days we also have [a helper package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) that does the format-finding for you:

```
> dt <- c("03/17/2003", "05/31/2003", "09/06/2003")
> anytime::anydate(dt)
[1] "2003-03-17" "2003-05-31" "2003-09-06"
>
```

This works for datetimes (using `anytime()`) and dates.