# Convert a string to Date by as.Date function

Tags: r, as.date

I have my string formatted as: 20170814 and wanted to convert to date by as.Date function but keep producing me 'NA".
This is my function:

```
a<-"20170814"
as.Date(a,"%y-%m/%d")
```

Can you please give me some help
Thanks

Comment: `as.Date(a,"%Y%m%d")`

Comment: You don't have dashes or slashes in your date, so don't include them in your `format` string.

Comment: Looks like this has been answered several time, two possible dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755425/what-are-the-standard-unambiguous-date-formats ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061469/cannot-convert-string-to-date-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use

```
as.Date(a, "%Y%m%d")
# [1] "2017-08-14"
```

because `"%Y%m%d"` is the description of the format of the character that you provide, which does not include `/` or `-`. Also, `Y` is needed when the year consists of 4 digits rather than 2.

Answer (score 2):

One solution with `lubridate`:

```
lubridate::ymd(a)

# [1] "2017-08-14"

class(lubridate::ymd(a))

# [1] "Date"
```

Answer (score 1):

The format is `%Y%m%d` and there is no `-`

```
as.Date(a,"%Y%m%d")
#[1] "2017-08-14"
```

---

Another option is `anytime` which can parse most of the formats and convert it to `Date` class

```
anytime::anydate(a)
#[1] "2017-08-14"

class(anytime::anydate(a))
#[1] "Date"
```